# ClassNotFoundException on IntrumentationRegistry while running Test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, android-junit

I have a utility class in my application that saves the User data from the server onto the SharedPreferences. I was trying to test the utilty class which is named `UserLocalStore.kt`

I wrote the following test class to do that:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class UserLocalStoreTest {

    lateinit var userLocalStore: UserLocalStore
    lateinit var context: Context
    lateinit var user: User

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context
        userLocalStore = UserLocalStore(context)
        userLocalStore.clearUserData()
        user = User(
            1,
            "test",
            "test@test.com",
            "test_url",
            "9817******",
            "test address",
            1,
            "yes",
            "2019-02-02",
            "2019-03-03",
            1
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun storeUserData() {
        //get an instance of the editor
        val userLocalDatabaseEditor = context.getSharedPreferences(
            Constants.USER_LOCAL_STORE_SHARED_PREF_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        ).edit()

        //use the editor to put the User model into the shared preference
        userLocalDatabaseEditor.putString(UserLocalStore.SERIALIZED_DATA_KEY, user.serialize())

        //assert that the data has indeed been stored
        val committed = userLocalDatabaseEditor.commit()
        assertTrue(committed)
    }
```

When I run the test method, I get a `ClassNotFoundException`. What I am doing wrong here?

The full error message is as:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/test/platform/app/InstrumentationRegistry

    at com.buyraksi.deliveryapp.util.UserLocalStoreTest.setUp(UserLocalStoreTest.kt:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I think I have my dependencies setup correctly as I have the following testing dependencies in my project app level `build.gradle`:

```
espresso_version = '3.2.0'
    /*
    Testing Dependencies
     */
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$espresso_version"
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing this: https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/setup#set-instrumentation-runner

Comment: @Traendy No I am not. Double checked it. I have other UI Tests running good, so it could not have been the case that I missed `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"`

Comment: Maybe there is confusion because you added two times
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$espresso_version" 
and 
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'